# Integral $\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1-x)}{x}\text{Li}_3\left({x} \right)\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, harmonic-numbers, polylogarithm

Is there a closed form for this integral?

$\displaystyle \int_0^1\frac{\ln(1-x)}{x}\text{Li}_3\left({x} \right)\,dx\\$

All I have been able to find, so far, is a numeric approximation of $-1.13348$

Comment: By IBP you reach $\int_0^1 \frac{\operatorname{Li}_2^2(x)}{x}dx$ which is solved here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/462389/definite-dilogarithm-integral-int1-0-frac-operatornameli-22xx-dx/463200#463200

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is:
$$\mathcal I=\zeta(2)\zeta(3)-3\zeta(5).$$
See e.g. [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/463200/73025).

Comment: Perfect !! Knowing the answer helps a lot ! I wish there was a comprehensive table of all these closed forms for definite integrals. The mathematical papers I found missed this particular one.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Leftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[2]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}\left(\,{#2}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

\begin{align}
&\color{#f00}{\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{1 - x} \over x}\,\Li{3}{x}\,\dd x} =
\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{1 - x} \over x}\,
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{x^{n} \over n^{3}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over n^{3}}\int_{0}^{1}\ln\pars{1 - x}x^{n - 1}\,\dd x
\label{1}\tag{1}
\end{align}

---

However,
\begin{align}
&\fbox{$\ds{\ \int_{0}^{1}\ln\pars{1 - x}x^{n - 1}\,\dd x\ }$} =
\lim_{\mu \to 0}\partiald{}{\mu}\int_{0}^{1}\pars{1 - x}^{\mu}x^{n - 1}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
\lim_{\mu \to 0}\partiald{}{\mu}
\bracks{\Gamma\pars{\mu + 1}\Gamma\pars{n} \over \Gamma\pars{\mu + n + 1}} =\
\fbox{$\ds{\ -\,{H_{n} \over n}\ }$}
\end{align}

---

Then $\ds{\pars{~\mbox{see expression}\ \eqref{1}~}}$,
$$
\color{#f00}{\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{1 - x} \over x}\,\Li{3}{x}\,\dd x} =
-\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{H_{n} \over n^{4}} =
\color{#f00}{{1 \over 6}\,\pi^{2}\zeta\pars{3} - 3\zeta\pars{5}}
$$

> $\ds{\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{H_{n} \over n^{4}} =
> {3\zeta\pars{5} - {1 \over 6}\,\pi^{2}}\,\zeta\pars{3} - }$ is given as formula $\pars{20}$
>   in the [MathWorld Harmonic Number page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HarmonicNumber.html) and it has been evaluated in a
>   [1995 David Borwein and Jonathan Borwein paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1995-123-04/S0002-9939-1995-1231029-X/).

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
I&=\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1-x)}{x}\operatorname{Li_3}(x)\ dx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^3}\int_0^1x^{n-1}\ln(1-x)\ dx=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n^4}=\zeta(2)\zeta(3)-3\zeta(5)
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using following recursion:

$$\operatorname{Li}_{0}(z) =\frac{z}{1-z}; \quad \operatorname{Li}_{n+1}(z) = \int_0^z \frac{\operatorname{Li}_n(t)}{t}$$