# Is a closed form possible for $\int\frac{\text{Li}_2(x)^2}{x}dx$?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, special-functions, polylogarithm

Can $\,\displaystyle\int\frac{\text{Li}_2(x)^2}{x}dx\,$ be calculated

by a sum/term of polylogarithm functions and the natural logarithm and polynomials (“closed form”) ?

For the special case $\,\displaystyle\int\limits_0^1\frac{\text{Li}_2(x)^2}{x}dx\,$ see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/462389/definite-dilogarithm-integral-int1-0-frac-operatornameli-22xx-dx/463200#463200) .

*Note:*

Closed forms are possible for $\,\displaystyle\int\frac{\text{Li}_n(x)^2}{x}dx\,$ where $n\in\mathbb{Z}\,$ and $\,n<2\,$ ,
e.g. $\,\displaystyle\int\frac{\text{Li}_1(x)^2}{x}dx = -2 \text{Li}_3(1-x) - 2 \text{Li}_2(1-x) \text{Li}_1(x) - \text{Li}_1(1-x) \text{Li}_1(x)^2 + C\,$

and $\,\displaystyle\int\frac{\text{Li}_0(x)^2}{x}dx = \frac{\text{Li}_0(x)}{x} - \text{Li}_1(2-x) + C\,$ .

Comment: Wolfram Alpha says there is no solution in elementary functions.

Comment: @FrankW. : I know, but that usually means nothing. :)

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\int\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(x)^2}{x}\ dx&\overset{IBP}{=}\operatorname{Li}_3(x)\operatorname{Li}_2(x)+\int\frac{\operatorname{Li}_3(x)\ln(1-x)}{x}\ dx\\
&=\operatorname{Li}_3(x)\operatorname{Li}_2(x)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^3}\int x^{n-1}\ln(1-x)\ dx
\end{align}

This is the simplest form I can get.

Comment: It looks like a dead end. :) --- But thank you for your efforts! Maybe it will help … ;)

Comment: you welcome. I wish I can simplify more. I have been struggling with such integral for a long time. look here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3305999/compute-int-01-2-frac-left-operatornameli-2x-right2x-dx

Comment: I know, and I gave you a suggestion for a slightly different view there. But I don't know if it will help you.