# Evaluating $\int_0^1\frac{\ln x\operatorname{Li}_2(x)\ln(1-x/2)}{x}\ dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, alternative-proof, harmonic-numbers

How to evaluate

$$\int_0^1\frac{\ln x\operatorname{Li}_2(x)\ln(1-\frac{x}{2})}{x}\ dx\ ?$$

I came across this integral while I was trying to calculate  [$\int_0^{1/2}\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2^2(x)}{x}\ dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3305999/compute-int-01-2-frac-left-operatornameli-2x-right2xdx?noredirect=1&lq=1) in a  different way and as follows,

---

Using [the identity](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=2598361216927327&set=a.222846247812181&type=3&theater)

$$\int_0^1\frac{\ln x\operatorname{Li}_2(x)}{1-ax}\ dx=\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2^2(a)}{2a}+3\frac{\operatorname{Li}_4(a)}{a}-2\zeta(2)\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(a)}{a}$$

Integrate both sides from $a=0$ to $a=1/2$ we get

$$\frac12\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2^2(a)}{a}\ da+3\operatorname{Li}_5\left(\frac12\right)-2\zeta(2)\operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac12\right)$$
$$=\int_0^1\ln x\operatorname{Li}_2(x)\left(\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}\frac{da}{1-ax}\right)\ dx=-\int_0^1\frac{\ln x\operatorname{Li}_2(x)\ln(1-\frac{x}{2})}{x}\ dx$$

its ok to use harmonic series but not the advanced ones like $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H_n^{(2)}}{n^32^n}$, $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H_n^{(3)}}{n^22^n}$,  $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H_n^{(4)}}{n2^n}$ and their alternating versions.

Comment: Not an answer but a question: for what does the $Li_2(x)$ stand? I'm unfamiliar with the notation.

Comment: @Strakatastic Dilogarithm