# Integrating $\frac{\log (1-x)}{x}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

How do I prove that $$\int_{0}^{1/2} \dfrac{\log (1-x)}{x} \mathrm{d}x=\dfrac{1}{2}\log^2{2}-\dfrac{\pi^2}{12}$$

I taylor expanded $\log(1-x)$ but ended up with a series I couldn't evaluate. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: I don't think so that 1÷2(log2)^2 would be present.

Comment: @AdityaKumar yes it would be

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$\frac{\log(1-x)}x=-\frac{(x+x^2/2+x^3/3+x^4/4+...)}x=-(1+x/2+x^2/3+x^3/4+...)$$
Now:
$$\int\frac{\log(1-x)}x{\rm d}x=-(x+x^2/2^2+x^3/3^3+...)=-{\rm Li}_2(x)$$
Now:
$$\int_0^{1/2}\frac{\log(1-x)}x{\rm d}x={\rm Li}_2(0)-{\rm Li}_2(1/2)=\frac{\log^22}2-\frac{\pi^2}{12}$$
since ${\rm Li}_2(0)=0$ and by [duplication formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/462659/67609):
$$\mathrm{Li}_2(x)+\mathrm{Li}_2(1-x)
=\frac{\pi^2}{6}-\log(x)\log(1-x)$$
Put $x=1/2$:
$$2\mathrm{Li}_2(1/2)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}-\log(1/2)\log(1/2)\implies \mathrm{Li}_2(1/2)=\frac{\pi^2}{12}-\frac12\log^2(2)$$

Comment: I suppose that $x^3/3^3$ would be $x^3/3^2$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici you know...