# Find $A =\int \frac{x \, dx}{e^x +1 }$

Tags: integration, polylogarithm

> Find $\displaystyle  A =\int \frac{x \, dx}{e^x +1 }$

Using Wolfram Alpha this yields  $-\operatorname{Li}_2(-e^x) + \frac{x^2}{2}-x \ln(e^x +1)$, where $\operatorname{Li}$ is the polylogaritm function. I am pretty really new to polylogarithms but I wanted to know how WA arrived at this result and if possible if there are any books that could help me grasp the use of these special functions in integration.

Comment: I'd say integrate by parts, and expand $\ln(1-e^{-x}) = -\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{e^{-x k}}{k}$

Comment: @user1952009 thanks i fixed it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that 
$$\begin{align}
\int\,\frac{x\,\exp(x)}{\exp(x)+1}\,\text{d}x&=\int\,x\,\text{d}\ln\big(\exp(x)+1\big)\\&=x\,\ln\big(\exp(x)+1\big)-\int\,\ln\big(\exp(x)+1\big)\,\text{d}x\,.
\end{align}$$
Then, we have that
$$\int\,\ln\big(\exp(x)+1\big)\,\text{d}x=\int\,\frac{\ln\Big(1-\big(-\exp(x)\big)\Big)}{\big(-\exp(x)\big)}\,\text{d}\big(-\exp(x)\big)=-\text{Li}_2\big(-\exp(x)\big)+C\,,$$
where $C$ is a constant (as $\text{Li}_2(z)=-\int_0^z\,\frac{\ln(1-t)}{t}\,\text{d}t$, according to [this](http://functions.wolfram.com/ZetaFunctionsandPolylogarithms/PolyLog/07/01/01/)).
Thus,
$$\begin{align}\int\,\frac{x}{\exp(x)+1}\,\text{d}x
&=\int\,\left(x-\frac{x\,\exp(x)}{\exp(x)+1}\right)\,\text{d}x
\\&=\frac{1}{2}x^2-x\,\ln\big(\exp(x)+1\big)-\text{Li}_{2}\big(-\exp(x)\big)+C\,.\end{align}$$

You can prove $\text{Li}_2(z)=-\int_0^z\,\frac{\ln(1-t)}{t}\,\text{d}t$ directly via
$$\begin{align}\text{Li}_2(z)&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\,\frac{z^k}{k^2}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\,\int_0^z\frac{t^{k-1}}{k}\,\text{d}t=\int_0^z\,\frac{1}{t}\,\sum_{k=1}^\infty\,\frac{t^k}{k}\,\text{d}t
\\
&=\int_0^z\,\frac{-\ln(1-t)}{t}\,\text{d}t\,,
\end{align}$$
for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$ with $|z|<1$.  Then, analytic continuation handles the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\int xe^{-nx}\,\mathrm{d}x=-\frac1{n^2}(nx+1)e^{-nx}+C$,
$$
\begin{align}
\int \frac{x\,\mathrm{d}x}{e^x+1}
&=\int x\left(e^{-x}-e^{-2x}+e^{-3x}+\dots\right)\mathrm{d}x\tag{1}\\
&=C-(x+1)e^{-x}+\tfrac14(2x+1)e^{-2x}-\tfrac19(3x+1)e^{-3x}+\dots\tag{2}\\
&=C-x\left(e^{-x}-\tfrac12e^{-2x}+\tfrac13e^{-3x}-\dots\right)+\left(-e^{-x}+\tfrac14e^{-2x}-\tfrac19e^{-3x}+\dots\right)\tag{3}\\
&=C-x\log\left(1+e^{-x}\right)+\mathrm{Li}_2\left(-e^{-x}\right)\tag{4}\\
&=C+x^2-x\log\left(e^x+1\right)-\tfrac{\pi^2}6-\mathrm{Li}_2\!\left(-e^x\right)-\tfrac12x^2\tag{5}\\
&=C_2+\tfrac12x^2-x\log\left(e^x+1\right)-\mathrm{Li}_2\!\left(-e^x\right)\tag{6}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: write $\frac1{e^x+1}$ as a geometric series
$(2)$: use the formula from above
$(3)$: separate terms
$(4)$: use the series for $\log(1+x)$ and $\mathrm{Li}_2(x)$
$(5)$: use $(5)$ from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/462659)
$(6)$: collect terms

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
I&=\int\frac{x\ dx}{e^x+1}=\int\frac{xe^{-x}}{1+e^{-x}}\ dx\overset{e^{-x}=y}{=}\int\frac{\ln y}{1+y}\ dy\\
&\overset{IBP}{=}\ln(1+y)\ln y-\int\frac{\ln(1+y)}{y}\ dy\\
&=\ln(1+y)\ln y-(-\operatorname{Li}_2(-y))\\
&=\ln(1+e^{-x})\ln(e^{-x})+\operatorname{Li}_2(-e^{-x})\\
&\{\color{red}{\text{use }\operatorname{Li}_2(-1/x)=-\operatorname{Li}_2(-x)-\frac12\ln^2x-\zeta(2)}\}\\
&=-x\ln\left(\frac{e^x+1}{e^x}\right)-\operatorname{Li}_2(-e^{x})-\frac12\ln^2(e^x)-\zeta(2)\\
&=-x\ln(1+e^x)+x^2-\operatorname{Li}_2(-e^{x})-\frac12x^2-\zeta(2)\\
&=\frac12x^2-x\ln(1+e^x)-\operatorname{Li}_2(-e^{x})-\zeta(2)+C
\end{align}

---

**Note:** The identity in red is proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3323423) but just replace $x$ with $-x$.